# Formatting issues with POST Requst C++

Tags: c++, arduino, httprequest

I am making a http POST request to a server with an Arduino board and therefore using C++. I can connect to the WiFi and server, the issue I am running into is that I am not able to send the variable data to this server. I have written what I believe is the same formatting of the string to JS and sent the request that way and it worked, but I cannot figure out how to make it work via C++.

The following is the code

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
Serial.println("connected to server");
String myval = "HelloWorld";

// Make a HTTP request:
String body = ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\r\n<soap:Body>\r\n<DataIn xmlns=\"http://www.config.com/\">\r\n<MyVal>" + myval + "</MyVal>\r\n</DataIn>\r\n</soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>\r\n");

client.print("POST http://eng/wsArduino.asmx HTTP/1.1\r\n");
client.print("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8\r\n");
client.print("Content-Length: ");
//client.println(myval.length());
//client.print("SOAPAction: \"http://www.config.com/DataIn\"\r\n");
client.println();
client.print(body);
client.println();
```

Are there any glaring issues, I cannot seem to figure out why this request will not work.

Thank you for any help. This is my first post so please let me know if I have broken any Stackoverflow etiquette.

Comment: what does "request will not work" mean?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

Comment: The thing is that a POST verb is one of the "verbs" that the server does take.

Comment: Your post has no information besides "it doesn't work". Please investigate all systems to see where the failure is located - even determining where yuur data is getting. Then ask again

Comment: Right above your comment is the HTTP error code The request verb is invalid. That is the only failure I am receiving within my system. The data I am sending is a variable called myval and that is the only data. What other systems would you like for me to check for more information. I am new to the whole wifi communication and not sure what else is needed. The code itself works fine it seems like it is the server rejecting the request.

Comment: I will attempt to try and find more information if possible and re-edit my post

Comment: Your `body` variable has a `myval` that isn't replaced with a value, creating an invalid string. You have no value for `Content-length:`. Look at your server to see the errors that it raises internally.

Answer (score -1):

This post should help: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=155218.0

Basically, format your params as json before passing them to the client.